# Java Card Shuffling App

Tags: java

I'm in the process of teaching myself Java and I'm trying to create a card shuffling app using the different things I have learned up to now. **I know there is an easier way to do this within one class but the goal of this is to implement as many things I have learned so far into one program.** The issue here is when I combine each suit into the combined array, the indexes of the combined array read "null". I know the issue is within the `Randomize` class.

***createCards Class:***

```
public class createCards {

decoyObject d = new decoyObject();

public void storeHearts(){
 String[] heartRay = new String[13];
 heartRay[0] = "AceH";
 int L = heartRay.length - 4;
 for(int i = 0; i <= L; i++){
     Integer h = i + 2;
     String heartPlace =  h.toString()+"H";
     heartRay[i+1] = heartPlace;
 }
 heartRay[10] = "JackH";
 heartRay[11] = "QueenH";
 heartRay[12] = "KingH";

 d.setHearts(heartRay);

}


 public void storeClubs(){
 String[] clubRay = new String[13];
 clubRay[0] = "AceC";
 int L = clubRay.length - 4;
 for(int i = 0; i <= L; i++){
     Integer h = i + 2;
     String clubPlace = h.toString() + "C";
     clubRay[i+1] = clubPlace;
 }
 clubRay[10] = "JackC";
 clubRay[11] = "QueenC";
 clubRay[12] = "KingC";

d.setClubs(clubRay);
}

 public void storeSpades(){
 String[] spadeRay = new String[13];
 spadeRay[0] = "AceS";
 int L = spadeRay.length - 4;
 for(int i = 0; i <= L; i++){
     Integer h = i + 2;
     String spadePlace = h.toString() + "S";
     spadeRay[i+1] = spadePlace;
 }
 spadeRay[10] = "JackS";
 spadeRay[11] = "QueenS";
 spadeRay[12] = "KingS";

d.setSpades(spadeRay);

}

 public void storeDiamonds(){
 String[] diamondRay = new String[13];
 diamondRay[0] = "AceD";
 int L = diamondRay.length - 4;
 for(int i = 0; i <= L; i++){
     Integer h = i + 2;
     String diamondPlace = h.toString() + "D";
     diamondRay[i+1] = diamondPlace;
 }
 diamondRay[10] = "JackD";
 diamondRay[11] = "QueenD";
 diamondRay[12] = "KingD";

d.setDiamonds(diamondRay);

}

}
```

***decoyObject Class***

```
public class decoyObject {

private String[] clubs;
private String[] hearts;
private String[] spades;
private String[] diamonds;
private String[] cards;

public decoyObject(){
    this.clubs = new String[13];
    this.hearts = new String[13];
    this.spades = new String[13];
    this.diamonds = new String[13];
    this.cards = new String[52];
}


public void setClubs(String[] clubs){
    this.clubs = clubs;
}


public String[] getClubs(){
    return clubs;
}


public void setHearts(String[] hearts){
    this.hearts = hearts;
}

public String[] getHearts(){
   return hearts;
}

public void setSpades(String[] spades){
    this.spades = spades;
}

public String[] getSpades(){
   return spades;
}

public void setDiamonds(String[] diamonds){
    this.diamonds = diamonds;
}

public String[] getDiamonds(){
   return diamonds;
}

public void setCards(String[] cards){
    this.cards = cards;
}

public String[] getCards(){
    return cards;
}

}
```

***Randomize Class***

I believe this Class is where the issue happens

```
public class Randomize{

createCards c = new createCards();
decoyObject d = new decoyObject();



public void randomizeCards(){

    c.storeHearts();
    c.storeClubs();
    c.storeDiamonds();
    c.storeSpades();

    //I believe the issue happens in the code below
    String[] randomHearts = d.getHearts();
    String[] randomClubs = d.getClubs();
    String[] randomDiamonds = d.getDiamonds();
    String[] randomSpades = d.getSpades();
    /***************************************/




    String[] combinedCards = new String[52];

    for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
        combinedCards[i] = randomHearts[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
        combinedCards[i+13] = randomClubs[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
        combinedCards[i+26] = randomDiamonds[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
        combinedCards[i+39] = randomSpades[i];
    }

//THE CODE BELOW PRINTS OUT NULL 52 TIMES   
for (String cards : combinedCards){
   System.out.println(cards);
}
/**********************************/

}

}
```

**Funthings Class**

This is the class with the main method.

```
public class Funthings {


public static void main(String[] args) {

   Randomize r = new Randomize();   
   r.randomizeCards();


}
}
```

Comment: Your decoy object never initializes the cards in the suits, they are all null.

Comment: I thought I was initializing them in the constructor of the decoyObject class!?

Comment: You're initializing them with array's full of null strings.

Comment: But in the createCards class I should be overwriting the null values then setting them in the decoyObject class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the same decoyObject from createCards to Randomize should resolve the issue.

Changes: Added a new method called **storeCards()** in **createCards** class which will return the **decoyObject** to the method call in **randomizeCards()**.

**createCards.java**

```
public class createCards {

decoyObject d = new decoyObject();

public decoyObject storeCards(){
    storeHearts();
    storeClubs();
    storeSpades();
    storeDiamonds();
    return d;
}

public void storeHearts(){
 String[] heartRay = new String[13];
 heartRay[0] = "AceH";
 int L = heartRay.length - 4;
 for(int i = 0; i <= L; i++){
     Integer h = i + 2;
     String heartPlace =  h.toString()+"H";
     heartRay[i+1] = heartPlace;
 }
 heartRay[10] = "JackH";
 heartRay[11] = "QueenH";
 heartRay[12] = "KingH";

 d.setHearts(heartRay);

}


 public void storeClubs(){
 String[] clubRay = new String[13];
 clubRay[0] = "AceC";
 int L = clubRay.length - 4;
 for(int i = 0; i <= L; i++){
     Integer h = i + 2;
     String clubPlace = h.toString() + "C";
     clubRay[i+1] = clubPlace;
 }
 clubRay[10] = "JackC";
 clubRay[11] = "QueenC";
 clubRay[12] = "KingC";

d.setClubs(clubRay);
}

 public void storeSpades(){
 String[] spadeRay = new String[13];
 spadeRay[0] = "AceS";
 int L = spadeRay.length - 4;
 for(int i = 0; i <= L; i++){
     Integer h = i + 2;
     String spadePlace = h.toString() + "S";
     spadeRay[i+1] = spadePlace;
 }
 spadeRay[10] = "JackS";
 spadeRay[11] = "QueenS";
 spadeRay[12] = "KingS";

d.setSpades(spadeRay);

}

 public void storeDiamonds(){
 String[] diamondRay = new String[13];
 diamondRay[0] = "AceD";
 int L = diamondRay.length - 4;
 for(int i = 0; i <= L; i++){
     Integer h = i + 2;
     String diamondPlace = h.toString() + "D";
     diamondRay[i+1] = diamondPlace;
 }
 diamondRay[10] = "JackD";
 diamondRay[11] = "QueenD";
 diamondRay[12] = "KingD";

d.setDiamonds(diamondRay);

}

}
```

**Randomize.java**

```
public class Randomize{

createCards c = new createCards();

public void randomizeCards(){
    decoyObject d = null;
    d = c.storeCards();

    //I believe the issue happens in the code below
    String[] randomHearts = d.getHearts();
    String[] randomClubs = d.getClubs();
    String[] randomDiamonds = d.getDiamonds();
    String[] randomSpades = d.getSpades();
    /***************************************/




    String[] combinedCards = new String[52];

    for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
        combinedCards[i] = randomHearts[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
        combinedCards[i+13] = randomClubs[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
        combinedCards[i+26] = randomDiamonds[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
        combinedCards[i+39] = randomSpades[i];
    }

//THE CODE BELOW PRINTS OUT NULL 52 TIMES   
for (String cards : combinedCards){
   System.out.println(cards);
}
/**********************************/

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the d.getHearts()at the Randomize , d is having an object of decoyObject class and you are going to deal with getHearts() of that object, but you are assigning values to arrays at the createCards class to the totally new object of the decoyObject class.

You are not using same object and you are using two different objects to value assign into assays and read values from arrays. That is why you are getting null values.

Good Luck !!!

Comment: I think I get what you are saying. So when I use c.storeHearts and even though c.storeHearts uses the "set" method of the decoyObject. decoyObject in the Randomize class will be null because each instantiation creates a unique class. Is that right?

Comment: You use the same class, but you create two different object. When you use the new key word it is created new object inside of the memory heap. I think it is better to crate a decoyObject object at the Randomize and pass it as a parameter of the constructor of the createCards. then you have to initialized values of the arrays of the decoyObject. Get back that object and store in the reference variable which is declared in Randomize. Then you can use that object to add values in to the combinedCards array in Randomize object. Try and let me know....